# C# Nullable DateTime Formatting Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, datetime-format

I have a nullable datetime column in my database.

In my viewmodel I have this property defined as follows:

```
public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

In my controller edit method I am trying to set the value of this property as follows:

```
 viewModel.ExpiryDate = topic.ExpiryDate.HasValue ?
          topic.ExpiryDate.Value.ToString("DD MMM YYYY") : null;
```

But I'm getting error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'
```

If I have the following i.e non nullable, it works fine without any errors:

```
 public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }

 viewModel.ExpiryDate = topic.ExpiryDate.ToString("DD MMM YYYY")
```

Comment: `viewModel.ExpiryDate` is a `DateTime?` but you're trying to assign a string. Isn't it clear? A `DateTime` has no format, what are you trying to achieve with `ToString("DD MMM YYYY")` here?

Comment: Clearly ExpiryDate should be assigned as Convert.ToDateTime(string format) or DateTime.ParseExact(string format).

Comment: ExpiryDate is a nullable DateTime value in my database table. In my view I want to format its display inside a textbox field. That is why i'm trying to format it when I assign it the the viewmodel.

Answer (score 3):

do this:

```
viewModel.ExpiryDate = topic.ExpiryDate.HasValue ?
          topic.ExpiryDate.Value : null;
```

With this code `.ToString("DD MMM YYYY")`, you're passing a string to a DateTime type property. Please make sure `viewModel.ExpiryDate` is also a **nullable DateTime type** since you're trying to assign a null value.

Comment: why not directly `viewModel.ExpiryDate = topic.ExpiryDate`?

Comment: not sure what is the type of both but you're correct fubo. :)

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", topic.ExpiryDate.Value)` or `DateTime.ParseExact(topic.ExpiryDate.Value, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` are possible if OP requires certain date format, i.e. topic.ExpiryDate is a string and not DateTime.

Comment: @ Tetsuya topic.ExpiryDate is a datetime value which can be nullable.